# a value of type struct cannot be assigned

Tags: c

I have a struct:

```
typedef struct mytime{
    float band;
    float elapsedTime;
} timeMs;
```

and in order to allocate memory:

```
timeMs *bands;
bands->band = (timeMs *) malloc(count * sizeof(timeMs));
bands->elapsedTime = (timeMs *) malloc(count * sizeof(timeMs));
```

and I am receiving:

> a value of type "timeMs *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type
>   "float"
>
> variable "bands" is used before its value is set

Also , inside:

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    bands->band[i] = 0.0;
    bands->elapsedTime[i] = 0.0;
}
```

I am receiving:

> expression must have pointer-to-object type

UPDATE:

I am using a function `timeMs  myfunction(...)` ,and I have an expression `bands[i].band += myfunction(..)`

and I am taking:

> ```
> no operator "+=" matches these operands
> operand types are: float += timeMs
> ```

--UPDATE---

I found the last problem .You must do :

```
bands[i].band += myfunction(..).band
bands[i].elapsedTime += myfunction(..).elapsedTime
```

Comment: can you post your whole code of `timeMs  myfunction(...)`?

Comment: You are returning the wrong type in `myfunction`; or, alternatively, the function in itself is correct but you only need the `band` structure element.

Comment: @Jongware:I am returning "mytime" ,hence 2 values , band and elapsedTime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for the struct, not for the individual fields.

```
timeMs *bands = malloc(count * sizeof *bands);
```

For the second error, try:

```
bands[i].band = 0.0;
```

Comment: @George It looks like `myfunction` doesn't return something that can be added to a `float`.

Comment: :My function returns "mytime".